# Como puedo setear la cabecera Autorization en AJAX con el método $.post en jquery ?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Tengo un problema al setear la cabecera Authorization con el metodo  `$.post` de jquery.

```
$.post("http://127.0.0.1:8000/newClient/", {
   beforeSend: function (xhr) {
     xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization','Basic ' + window.localStorage.getItem('token'));
   },
   data: JSON.stringify(validData)
   }, function (response) {
         console.log("Esto es el token ",window.localStorage.getItem('token'));
         var r = JSON.parse(response);
         console.log(r.status);
})
```

El token lo tengo bien seteado y lo obtengo bien en la respuesta, he hecho muchas peticiones AJAX con jquery pero nunca con el metodo `$.post`,  puede ser que este metodo no acepte el seteado de cabeceras?

Traza del error.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setRequestHeader' of undefined
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo he solucionado creando una función javascript `beforeSend`.

```
var beforeSend = function (xhr) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Token ' + window.localStorage.getItem('token'));
}
```

Y luego configurando el ajaxSetup con esa función.

```
$.ajaxSetup({
   beforeSend: beforeSend
});
```

Entonces finalmente el código quedaría así, sin la cabecera.

```
$.post("http://127.0.0.1:8000/newClient/", {
   data: JSON.stringify(validData)
   }, function (response) {
         console.log("Esto es el token ",window.localStorage.getItem('token'));
         var r = JSON.parse(response);
         console.log(r.status);
})
```